# JavaScript - Expresión regular que no permita números en la mitad

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando hacer una expresión regular la cual debe permitir:

Mayúsculas y minúsculas
Tildes

Estoy trabajando con JavaScript y esto fue lo que realice

```js
const word = "Esto es una prueba"
const regex = /[^a-zA-ZÁ-ÿ ]+$/g
console.log(regex.test(word))
```

Al momento de ejecutarla sale bien, lo extraño es que cuento hago la prueba con un número en la mitad de la palabra lo toma bien también y no debería ser así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe como pueda hacer para que no valide el número?

Comment: Prueba a poner el `^` antes de los corchetes -> `^[a-zA-ZÁ-ÿ ]+$`, si lo pones dentro no significa inicio de línea, si no que busca el símbolo en si mismo. Puedes verlo funcionar en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hUKTgB/1)

Comment: Un unicornio llora cada vez que ponen el código como imagen siendo que al comienzo pusieron algo de código como texto ;)

Comment: Cada vez que ponen codigo en imagen muere un gatito :(

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@. Conoce las reglas de la comunidad [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1):

Tienes la aserción `$` al final de la expresión regular y es posible que por eso no te está validando de manera correcta.

Sin eliminamos dicha aserción, la validación se hace tal y como esperas.

```js
//Prueba con números
const withNumber = "Esto es 1 prueba";
if(!/[^a-zA-ZÁ-ÿ ]/g.test(withNumber)){
  console.log("esta bien");
} else {
  console.log("no esta bien");
}

//Prueba sin numeros
const word = "Esto es una prueba";
if(!/[^a-zA-ZÁ-ÿ ]/g.test(word)){
  console.log("esta bien");
} else {
  console.log("no esta bien");
}
```

Algo de documentación sobre las [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) y algo de documentación sobre las [aserciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) en MDN.

Comment: Sería interesante conocer los motivos del voto negativo. Si estoy errado en mi percepción del caso o en mi respuesta, no solo yo sino toda la comunidad puede aprender. Espero que quien haya dado el voto negativo nos pueda dar feedback o que publique la respuesta correcta.